# Python Cassandra Query LIKE

Tags: python, cassandra

How can I populate data dynamically with LIKE queries

I tried this:

```
q1 = sesi.execute("SELECT * FROM document WHERE judul LIKE '%s' ", "cluster" )
```

But I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  File "/var/www/app_arsip/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2012, in execute
>
> return self.execute_async(query, parameters, trace, custom_payload, timeout, execution_profile, paging_state).result()
>
> File "/var/www/app_arsip/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2049, in execute_async
>
> future = self._create_response_future(query, parameters, trace, custom_payload, timeout, execution_profile, paging_state)
>
> File "/var/www/app_arsip/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2109, in _create_response_future
>   query_string = bind_params(query_string, parameters, self.encoder)
>   File "/var/www/app_arsip/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/query.py", line 826, in bind_params
>   return query % tuple(encoder.cql_encode_all_types(v) for v in params)
>
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I hope someone can help me

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change your query, remove single quote and enclose your parameter with `[]`**

```
q1 = sesi.execute("SELECT * FROM document WHERE judul LIKE %s", ["%cluster%"] )
```

Comment: It has not worked yet, and it does not display results

Comment: What are you doing with this query ??  are you using SASIIndex ?

Comment: I want to find a title that contains the words I input,

And I have used SASI Index in the document table

Comment: CREATE CUSTOM INDEX search_title ON project.document ( title ) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = { 
'analyzed' : 'true', 
'analyzer_class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.NonTokenizingAnalyzer', 
'case_sensitive' : 'falsse', 
'mode' : 'CONTAINS' 
};

Comment: You want to search document whose judul contains the word `cluster` ??

Comment: Try to use `q1 = sesi.execute("SELECT * FROM document WHERE judul LIKE %s", ["%cluster%"] )`